# Caption for subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm using the below script to display a figure. The problem is that I don't know how to put subcaption for each subfigure. I don't want to use any other packages. Any advice please?

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{fig1.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{fig2.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{fig3.png}\\
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{fig4.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{fig5.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{fig6.png}

\caption{big_caption.}
\label{label1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132821/subfigure-without-using-caption-packages help? May I ask why you don't want to use a package?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. nope. As I want normal captions like (a),(b),...

Comment: because in the conference I'm writing in they aren't allowing this. Any suggestions? I can try using other packages, and hope it will work

Comment: If the conference doesn't allow any packages, it doesn't allow any packages. But take the example I linked to above, and remove `\thefigure` from `\renewcommand\themysfig{\thefigure(\alph{mysfig})}`. Or if you just need (a),(b) etc., you can perhaps add it in the pictures themselves.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. how to add them in the pictures themselves?

Comment: Well I don't know how you make those pictures ... If they are e.g. plots from Matlab or Matplotlib, add a text element to the axes before saving as PNG. You could of course also open the PNGs in any image editor that allows you to add text, and do it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the subfigure captions to show up in the `\listoffigures` and you can remember the alphabet, you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% for images only
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\par
\makebox[0.32\linewidth]{(a)}
\makebox[0.32\linewidth]{(b)}
\makebox[0.32\linewidth]{(c)}
\vspace{\baselineskip}\par
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image}
\par
\makebox[0.32\linewidth]{(d)}
\makebox[0.32\linewidth]{(e)}
\makebox[0.32\linewidth]{(f)}
\vspace{\baselineskip}\par
\caption{big caption.}
\label{label1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: do it yourself captions]